# Need help translating this query to NHibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, nhibernate, orm

Can someone help me translate this query to NHibernate Criteria? Or is Criteria not suited for this?

Query:

```
SELECT b.*
 FROM Bookmarks b
 JOIN (SELECT tg.BookmarkId
        FROM TagsBookmarks tg
        JOIN Tags t ON t.id = tg.TagId
        WHERE t.Title IN ('c#','tutorials')
      GROUP BY tg.BookmarkId
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Title) = 2) x ON x.BookmarkId = b.Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not allow subqueries in the `from` clause.  You can rewrite this using `in` instead:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Bookmarks b
where b.id in (SELECT tg.BookmarkId
               FROM TagsBookmarks tg JOIN
                    Tags t
                    ON t.id = tg.TagId
               WHERE t.Title IN ('c#','tutorials')
               GROUP BY tg.BookmarkId
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Title) = 2
              )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also give me the query in Criteria?

Comment: @Mr.nuub . . . That is outside my expertise.

Comment: See http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries for how to write subqueries using criteria, and you can do `having` clauses by putting a restriction on a projection, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054309/nhibernate-get-distinct-results-based-on-a-column-but-retrieve-all-columns/5918967#5918967